# HomeWidgetBackgroundService error using es.antonborri

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics

Error on homewidget
Crahslytics error : DartExecutor.java line 421
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor$DartCallback.toString

logs :

> `Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
> Unable to create service es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String io.flutter.view.FlutterCallbackInformation.callbackLibraryPath' on a null object reference
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:4240)
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$200 (ActivityThread.java:240)
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2072)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:238)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7853)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:984)
>
> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
> Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String io.flutter.view.FlutterCallbackInformation.callbackLibraryPath' on a null object reference
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor$DartCallback.toString (DartExecutor.java:421)
> java.lang.String.valueOf (String.java:2924)
> java.lang.StringBuilder.append (StringBuilder.java:132)
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.executeDartCallback (DartExecutor.java:175)
> es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundService.onCreate (HomeWidgetBackgroundService.kt:55)
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:4228)
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$200 (ActivityThread.java:240)
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2072)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:238)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7853)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:984)`

How to fix this issue

Im stuck on this. Need help as Im a beginner with flutter.

I think it have something to do with this as this is the only part of the codebase that is calling the homewidgetbackgroundservice

A part of android manifest

```
     <!-- Used for Background Work -->
                <receiver
                    android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundReceiver"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.action.BACKGROUND" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service
                    android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundService"
                    android:exported="true"
                    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
                <receiver
                    android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
            </application>
        </manifest>
```